# Enviar correo por Amazon SES sin verificar

Tags: laravel-5, email, amazon-s3

Quisiera saber como se envían correo masivamente por amazon SES pero sin verificar cada correo, estoy usando  laravel y ya logre enviar correos usando smtp pero ambos estaban verificados

el problema no es en laravel sino en amazon , que tengo que hacer para que amazon ses me envié correo sin verificar cada correo

Comment: ¿por qué no verificar los correos?

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas enviar un ticket a Amazon, te paso el link lo dice en sus preguntas frecuentes.
https://aws.amazon.com/es/ses/faqs/